# Element not found SteamDB - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, highcharts, selenium-chromedriver

I am quite new to programming and have been experimenting with Selenium.

I want to download an XLS file from URL "https://steamdb.info/tech/Engine/Unity/".

Whenever I try to find the element on the download button, it returns

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='highcharts-0tuszdg-0']/svg/g[6]/g/image"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)"
```

I want to click on this element, which opens a Download XLS button, and then to click on that button to download the XLS.

This is the code that I've been using:

```
ser = Service('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe')
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)

#implicit wait
s.implicitly_wait(0.5)
#maximize browser
s.maximize_window()
#launch URL
s.get("https://steamdb.info/tech/Engine/Unity/")
s.implicitly_wait(0.5)
s.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='highcharts-0tuszdg-0']/svg/g[6]/g/image")
s.implicitly_wait(0.5)
l =s.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-0tuszdg-0"]/div/ul/li[2]')
#perform click
l.click()
```

I realize I am very new to this and am probably doing all sorts of things wrong. Hope you can steer me in the right direction.

Thanks!
CIS

Answer (score 1):

```
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get("https://steamdb.info/tech/Engine/Unity/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"svg > g.highcharts-exporting-group > g > image"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"ul.highcharts-menu > li:nth-child(2)"))).click()
```

If you want to use Options in conjunction with Service you should do it like so I used Chromedriver manager to make sure the binaries are correctly set up.
From there you need to wait for the element to be clickable using Webdriver waits and then click on those elements.

1. Implicit waits are for page loads not element finding so use explicits.
2. Chromeoptions is depreciated along with driver.find_element_by_*.
3. Incorrect xpaths selected.

Import:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```